# Creating a spatial reference in arcpy from projection name

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, error-000628

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2, Python 2.7. I want to create a spatial reference from the name of a projection, e.g. NAD_1983_BC_Environment_Albers, using the arcpy tool arcpy.CreateSpatialReference_management(). 
Consider this:

```
projName = "NAD_1983_BC_Environment_Albers"
#Replace underscores with spaces, works fine.
sr = arcpy.CreateSpatialReference_management(projName.replace('_',' '))
```

No issues here. Also, I tried the example in the arcpy documentation [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000079000000):

```
projName = "NAD 1983 StatePlane California V FIPS 0405 (US Feet)"
sr = arcpy.CreateSpatialReference_management(projName)
```

This also works fine. So, why does the following generate an error?

```
projName = "NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_9N"
#Tried both with and without converting underscores to spaces    
sr = arcpy.CreateSpatialReference_management(projName.replace('_',' '))

ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Create Spatial Reference). Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter spatial_reference.
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Your code worked on my machine arcpy 10.1: `>>> import arcpy
>>> projName = "NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_9N"
>>> sr = arcpy.CreateSpatialReference_management(projName.replace('_', ' '))
>>> print sr
PROJCS['NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_9N',GEOGCS .....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unclear why you prefer the name to the factory code. You can use the srid and there is no fuss with spaces/underscores.

For projected systems: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/018z/pdf/projected_coordinate_systems.pdf

For geog. Systems: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/018z/pdf/geographic_coordinate_systems.pdf

If you are intent on using the name and converting spaces/underscores,maybe try using your replace statement in the declaration rather than inside the arcpy command. That may be the cause of the second part of the error.

Like:

```
projname = ("name of proj").replace('_',' ')
```

Comment: Using the srid (in this case, 26909) as in  CreateSpatialReference_management(26909) worked for me. Thank you.